# Enable compression for the following resources to reduce

Tags: compression, gzip, pagespeed

I am using Gtmetrix to test my page load time. I enabled gzip compression on my site by adding code to .htaccess

.htaccess code:

mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*

but still Gtmetrix showing the below warning
Enable compression for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 687.5KiB (72% reduction).

Compressing http://www.hengleasing.com/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/js/autoptimize_bad2eb0827122f50acbfa0d977d7269a.js could save 526.3KiB (72% reduction).

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [POST Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could as a workaround disable "serve as static files" in autoptimize?